# Call a gradle task from java class

Tags: java, gradle

Is it possible to invoke a Gradle task from my java class?

Some team has created a Gradle plugin we just want to reuse it so is there a way to invoke Gradle plugin from Java class?

Comment: Sounds like what you want is the functionality not the task itself. Can the gradle task be refactored such that the functionality you need is available as a shared library both can use?

Answer (score 2):

You can probably do it using the [Gradle Tooling API](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/embedding.html) that allows you to embed Gradle into your own custom software. Among the features offered by this API is the ability to:

> Execute a build and listen to stdout and stderr logging and
>   progress (e.g. the stuff shown in the 'status bar' when you run on the
>   command line).

Comment: Of course there is another way around that can be more appropriate: extract the code you are interested in into separate library. Then wrap this into Gradle plugin or call it from your Java application.